# IE label исчезает при нажатии tab

Tags: css, internet-explorer, label

Есть поля ввода текста с label слева от них к каждому. Только в Internet Explorer (9) при нажатии на Tab на клавиатуре с фокусом на следующее поле ввода у него исчезает его label и поле ввода "прыгает" влево на расстояние длинны label.

Структура:

```
div
    span
        label
    input
```

Стиль:

```
div
    display flex
    align-items center
    overflow hidden

label
    white-space nowrap
    width min-content
    padding-left 1px
span
    display inline-block
    width 100%
input 
    display inline-block
    width 100%
    margin-left 0
    box-sizing border-box
```

Как заставить IE держать label на своем месте?

Получается, у input ширина в 100% считается неверно, вылазит за див. IE сам сдвигает все влево, чтобы показать остаток input, как убрать это поведение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу вам порекомендовать переделать разметку и стили следующим образом:

```css
.form {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.form__line +.form__line {
  margin-top: .5em;
}

.form__label {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.form__input-holder {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.form__input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" class="form">
  <div class="form__line">
    <label for="input1" class="form__label">Поле номер 1</label>
    <div class="form__input-holder">
      <input id="input1" type="text" class="form__input">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form__line">
    <label for="input2" class="form__label">Поле 2</label>
    <div class="form__input-holder">
      <input id="input2" type="text" class="form__input">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form__line">
    <label for="input3" class="form__label">Надпись большой ширины</label>
    <div class="form__input-holder">
      <input id="input3" type="text" class="form__input">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form__line">
    <label for="input4" class="form__label">Средняя надпись</label>
    <div class="form__input-holder">
      <input id="input4" type="text" class="form__input">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form__line">
    <label for="input5" class="form__label">И еще одна</label>
    <div class="form__input-holder">
      <input id="input5" type="text" class="form__input">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

P.S. подозреваю, что проблемы из-за свойства-значения `width: min-content`, которое не поддерживается всеми версиями ИЕ и Эдж.